# How to make a drawing to move to the center of the panel?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

There is a food button that allows you to feed the fish and jellyfish with a worm and then the animals swim to the center of the panel to eat the worm. I was able to do this but the problem is that sometimes (it depends on the specific place of the drawing in the panel) I have a problem that the fish or jellyfish get stuck from side to side until they reach the center and it does not look good, the question is how can this be fixed?

I made a video of my program running where you can see the above problem.you can see the problem at the 0:16 of the video with the yellow fish.
link : https://vimeo.com/702495703

I attached my code that makes them move to the center of the panel:

```
    public void EatTheWorm() {
        // changing the drection of the fish to the center of the panel
        if(x_front > panel.getWidth()/2)
           x_dir = -1;
        else
           x_dir=1;
        if(y_front > panel.getHeight()/2)
           y_dir = -1;
        else
           y_dir=1;
        this.x_front+=horSpeed*x_dir;
        this.y_front+=verSpeed*y_dir;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without a [mre] that we can copy to our IDE, run, and test.  What are the fish supposed to do?

Comment: I'm creating 5 threads that start to move in the aquarium at different speeds of x and y in the run() method and as soon as I press the button called "food" (located at the bottom of the panel) they should just get to the center of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

You only give a very little of your code. From my observation, I think this is that happening.

The fish movement is determined by two factors at every tick. The vertical direction and horizontal direction. Seems the fish cannot move pure vertical or horizontal. It has to move diagonally.

Consider a situation, when a fish sits at the center of the screen above the worm. At the next tick, the fish move forward and downward. When it moves forward, it across the center so it want to turn back because if it keeps it direction, it will swim further away from the worm. At the next tick, it turns back and across the center again. This iteration continue until the worm is eaten. This casts an illusion of the fish bouncing back and forth.
[image]

I think this is not only a technical challenge but also a design challenge. How would you design the fish to move when this situation happens? Maybe you would allow the fish to straight descend to the worm? But it might looks unnatural. Or you would order the fish to swim forward a little bit and turn back follow a path? That is up to you.

[image]